# Regex - Keep Bookmark but remove hyperlinks

Tags: php, regex

In documents In have multiple instance of

```
(i) <a href="#_ftnrefx" name="_ftnx" title="" id="_ftnx">[X]</a>
as bookmarks

and 
(ii) <a href="http://www.somedomain.com/somepageurl">Some text</a>
```

Regex help needed for removing all hyperlinks (as in (ii)) but keep the bookmark links (as in (i). In 2, would need to keep the text "Some text" and just remove the hyperlink.

Thanks.

Comment: What happens to the `[X]`? Have you tried any regexes yet, or a parser?

Comment: What are requirements, `<a href` starting with an `#` anchor should be removed or depends on innerhtml? [See demo](https://regex101.com/r/mM3gU8/2).

Comment: <a href starting with # anchor should be kept as is. 
Others need to be removed.

Comment: load in DonDocument, find with xpath `//a[starts-with(@href, 'http://']` desired tags, create text node with that $a->nodeValue, replace . less than 10 lines

Answer (score 0):

This snippet should work

```php
echo preg_replace(
   '/<a[^>]+href\s*=\s*[\'"][^#][^>]+>([^<]+)<\s*\/a\s*>/', 
   '$1', 
   '<a href="http://www.somedomain.com/somepageurl">Some text</a>'
);
```

Comment: I tried:
preg_replace('#<a.*?>(.*?)</a>#i', '\1', $html);

It keeps the text but strips all hyperlink.
As against this, I would want to keep hyperlinks for links which have # ie bookmarks on same page.

Comment: There is no `g` modifier in PHP.